# at what point in the ancient world would a world war be feasible?

Tags: warfare, alternate-history

According to our history books, there was a massive earthquake in the ancient world which left effects on a global scale. Millions of people were killed in this tragic point in history. However, the earthquake revealed held by the planet for thousands of years with its devastation. Ancient tombs were uncovered all across the world on every continent, which held vast treasures. Each of these ancient tombs held relics and weapons of war made by the gods. These relics ranged from individual weapons (flying sandals, magic barriers, and magic bows), to the super weapons of the day, (on par with Archimedes death ray, lightning bolt generator, Hephaestus's forge). This revelation caused the world's first arms race, long before the governments of the Soviets and Yankees. However, this arms race went hot, and caused a global conflict to become the dominant superpower. Nations made it a priority to protect their own stockpiles of relics, all the while invading other empires for theirs. These weapons were used on a massive scale to give their armies and edge, as empires duked it out in the planet's First World War, or WW1.

I am trying to place this war in history as far back as possible. The empires of Rome, Persia, and such did not have the sophisticated tech we do today. Certain things I must consider would be these powers coordinating their armies across vast distances, as well as maintain some coherence of goals and movements. How far back in our history would a war on this scale be possible? What are other capabilities of these empires would I need them to take into account?

Comment: Could you perhaps give us details about what you mean by a world war, "Rome, Persia, and such did not have the sophisticated tech we do today" - but if every single soldier in their army effectively has the weapon of a Greek demigod, then how is ancient Persia *not* acceptable as an answer. Can you clarify your questions parameters with a little more detail?

Comment: At no point in ancient history would a world war be possible, very obviously. In fact, the first point in history at which a world war became sort-of possible is the dawn of the modern age; and guess what, they did have the Thirty Years' War, which was in a way a prefiguration of a world war, complete with action in African, Asian and American theaters. You are of course free to use the magic relics to accelerate the development of mankind and to enhance the war making capacities of the various polities; but then the world you will get will be very very different from the ancient world.

Answer (score 1):

I can give some general sense of what the world was like in a few large time periods, that might help (this is all from [Sapiens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062316117), which I highly recommend reading if you want a broad sense of world history)

- 10,000 bc: first agricultural civilizations. Small towns of no more than 1000. No major civilization. Agricultural revolutions happened independently in accordance with the below picture. [image]
- 3000-5000 bc: a few well-developed civilizations. Sumerians in the fertile crescent now have cities. Hard to say about american civilizations at the time.
- 400AD-3000 BC: juicy period. This may be a decent setting for you. Greece and Rome developed (greece first). By 0 AD, Rome had (I think?) over a million people. Tenochtitlan (capital of the Aztec empire) had ~200,000-400,000 people living in it. Most major ethnic regions had larger cities developed at this time. Fall of Rome in 410 AD put a real damper on all this and plunged western civilization into the dark ages essentially until the renaissance.
- 1450 AD: world collapsed into about 5 major centers of civilization. Europe just leaving the dark ages, Arab, Indian, and east Asian civilizations doing quite well, Aztec/Incas thriving and eating corn (Tenochtitlan one of the largest cities in the world at the time). Aztec/Incas utterly destroyed by spanish conquistadors by ~1520 AD.
  [image]

Comment: There was no Greek civilization whatsoever in the 3rd millennium BCE. Tenochtitlan did not exist at all in the 1st century CE, and I am quite certain that there was no Aztec empire at that time... (And you are giving all the time intervals backwards; 400 CE - 3,000 BCE is a bizarre way of writing 3,000 BCE - 400 CE.) (Also, *Sapiens* is one man's idiosyncratic synopsis of the raise of mankind. It's a good book, but don't take it as representing in any way a generally accepted overview. On the other hand, I don't know of any other recent attempt at a short synthesis of the entire subject.)

Comment: @AlexP Possibly germs, guns and steel by Jared Diamond? Haven't read Sapiens so can't give a proper comparison review.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps: In my opinion, the major difference between Yuval Harari *Sapiens* and Jared Diamond's *Guns, Germs, and Steel* is that *Sapiens* in an honest attempt at a synthesis. Whatever it is, and different people have different opinions on the subject, *GG&S* is not an attempt at a historical synthesis; and, to be fair, it doesn't pretend to be one.